# Bulk Email Sending Using VBA Run Time Concern

Tags: excel, vba, cdo.message

[image]
I have written a code for my purpose to send bulk email dynamically (Name,Document,Expiry date,email address will be changed dynamically)..Everything is working fine but it take a approximately ( 4 Second/Mail sent for without using array and 2 sec / mail sent using array)...Any one know another way around to make it a little bit fast?.. Before running the macro please edit .To = "Your email id", and password..Thanks.
For Sending 1000 mail it will take approximately 67 & 33 minute.. If possible i want to make it 67 & 33 Second..Is it possible??
Email is sent if expired day is after 30/7/0 day from today.

Process 1

```
Public Sub SentRemainder()
Dim RemainingDay As Long, L As Integer, t1 As Long, t2 As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
t1 = Timer()
Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
lastrow = Sheets("Personal").Cells(1048576, 2).End(xlUp).Row
With Sheets("Personal")
For i = 3 To lastrow
    If .Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" Then
         RemainingDay = .Cells(i, 4).Value - Now() + 1
    ElseIf .Cells(i, 4).Value = "" Then
       Exit For
    End If
    If RemainingDay = 30 Or RemainingDay = 7 Or RemainingDay = 0 Then
    SendEmailUsingGmail .Cells(i, 1).Value, .Cells(i, 2).Value, Format(.Cells(i, 4).Value, "DD-MMM-YYYY"), .Cells(i, 5).Value, RemainingDay
    L = L + 1
 '    ElseIf RemainingDay < 0 Then
 '        .Range(.Cells(i, "A"), .Cells(i, "E")).ClearContents
 '        .Range(.Cells(i, "A"), .Cells(lastrow - 1, "E")).Value = .Range(.Cells(i + 1, "A"), .Cells(lastrow, "E")).Value
'        .Range(.Cells(lastrow, "A"), .Cells(lastrow, "E")).ClearContents
End If
Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
MsgBox "Email sent : " & L & "Nos."
t2 = Timer()
MsgBox "Time taken to run this code: " & t2 - t1

End Sub
'Enable Tools > References > Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library
 Public Sub SendEmailUsingGmail(Name As String, Document As String, ExpiryDate As String, EmailAddress As String, RemainingDay As Long)
Dim NewMail As CDO.Message                                 'For Creating email collaboration.
Dim mailConfiguration As CDO.Configuration          'For mail configuration
Dim fields As Variant                                                 'For email field data.
Dim msConfigurationURL As String                           'For storing the server URL (CDO).
On Error GoTo Err:
    'early binding
    Set NewMail = New CDO.Message                          'Create the collaboration.
    Set mailConfiguration = New CDO.Configuration   'Create configuration.
    mailConfiguration.Load -1                                       'Load all default configurations
    Set fields = mailConfiguration.fields                        'Set configuration field to previous field.
    
    'Set All Email Properties
    With NewMail
        .From = "Your gmail address"            'From which email address email will be sent.
        .To = EmailAddress                                            'Where to send the email.
        .CC = ""                                                              'If you need to use CC then add email address.
        .BCC = ""                                                            'If you need to use BCC then add email address.
        .Subject = Document & " Expired in " & RemainingDay & " Day."    'Subject of Email..Dynamically it will change for every recepient.
                                                                                                       'For increasing readibility use _ .Here textbody is written.
        .TextBody = "Hi " & Name & "," & vbNewLine & _
        "Your " & Document & " will expire on " & ExpiryDate & _
        ".You have " & RemainingDay & " day to renew your " & Document & "." & "Please renew your " & Document & "." & _
        vbNewLine & "Thank You." & vbNewLine & "Md.Ismail Hosen"
        '.AddAttachment     'Here i need to edit.
    End With
    msConfigurationURL = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration"           'For decrease word in below line.
    With fields
        .Item(msConfigurationURL & "/smtpusessl") = True                                         'Enable SSL Authentication
        .Item(msConfigurationURL & "/smtpauthenticate") = 1                                      'SMTP authentication Enabled
        .Item(msConfigurationURL & "/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"                     'Set the SMTP server details
        .Item(msConfigurationURL & "/smtpserverport") = 465                                     'Set the SMTP port Details....Check it in Gmail. Port may be 25/465/587
        .Item(msConfigurationURL & "/sendusing") = 2                                                'Send using default setting
        .Item(msConfigurationURL & "/sendusername") = "Your gmail address"        'Your gmail address
        .Item(msConfigurationURL & "/sendpassword") = "Your gmail password"                              'Your password or App Password(If 2F is on).
        .Update                                                                                                                             'Update the configuration fields
    End With
    With NewMail
        .Configuration = mailConfiguration                      'Set NewMail configuration to updated configuration.
        .Send
    End With
    'MsgBox "Your email has been sent", vbInformation
Exit_Err:
'Release object memory
Set NewMail = Nothing
Set mailConfiguration = Nothing
Exit Sub            'This is so much important if you want to run the sub multiple times.
Err:
Select Case Err.Number
Case -2147220973                                    'Could be because of Internet Connection
    MsgBox "Check your internet connection." & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
Case -2147220975                                     'Incorrect credentials User ID or password
    MsgBox "Check your login credentials and try again." & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
Case 0                              'Case 0 means code run smoothly and you need to exit this sub.
    GoTo Exit_Err:
Case Else                                                   'Report other errors
    MsgBox "Error encountered while sending email." & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Select
Resume Exit_Err
End Sub
```

Process 2 Using Array:

```
Public Sub SentRemainder2()
Dim RemainingDay As Long, L As Integer, t1 As Long, t2 As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
t1 = Timer()
Dim i As Long

Dim arr As Variant
With Sheets("Personal")
arr = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(.Cells(1048576, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 5)).Value
End With

Dim NewMail As CDO.Message                                 'For Creating email collaboration.
Dim mailConfiguration As CDO.Configuration          'For mail configuration
Dim fields As Variant                                                 'For email field data.
Dim msConfigurationURL As String                           'For storing the server URL (CDO).
On Error GoTo Err:
'early binding
Set NewMail = New CDO.Message                          'Create the collaboration.
Set mailConfiguration = New CDO.Configuration   'Create configuration.
mailConfiguration.Load -1                                       'Load all default configurations
Set fields = mailConfiguration.fields                        'Set configuration field to previous field.
msConfigurationURL = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration"           'For decrease word in below line.
With fields
    .Item(msConfigurationURL & "/smtpusessl") = True                                         'Enable SSL Authentication
    .Item(msConfigurationURL & "/smtpauthenticate") = 1                                      'SMTP authentication Enabled
    .Item(msConfigurationURL & "/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"                     'Set the SMTP server details
    .Item(msConfigurationURL & "/smtpserverport") = 465                                     'Set the SMTP port Details....Check it in Gmail. Port may be 25/465/587
    .Item(msConfigurationURL & "/sendusing") = 2                                                'Send using default setting
    .Item(msConfigurationURL & "/sendusername") = "Your Gmail Address"        'Your gmail address
    .Item(msConfigurationURL & "/sendpassword") = "Your Gmail Password"                              'Your password or App Password(If 2F is on).
    .Update                                                                                                                             'Update the configuration fields
End With

For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
RemainingDay = arr(i, 4) - Now() + 1
If RemainingDay = 30 Or RemainingDay = 7 Or RemainingDay = 0 Then
    With NewMail
        .Configuration = mailConfiguration
        .From = "Your Gmail Address"            'From which email address email will be sent.
        .To = arr(i, 5)                                            'Where to send the email.
        .CC = ""                                                              'If you need to use CC then add email address.
        .BCC = ""                                                            'If you need to use BCC then add email address.
        .Subject = arr(i, 2) & " Expired in " & RemainingDay & " Day."    'Subject of Email..Dynamically it will change for every recepient.
                                                                                                       'For increasing readibility use _ .Here textbody is written.
        .TextBody = "Hi " & arr(i, 1) & "," & vbNewLine & _
        "Your " & arr(i, 2) & " will expire on " & arr(i, 4) & _
        ".You have " & RemainingDay & " day to renew your " & arr(i, 2) & "." & "Please renew your " & arr(i, 2) & "." & _
        vbNewLine & "Thank You." & vbNewLine & "Md.Ismail Hosen"
        '.AddAttachment     'Here i need to edit.
        .Send
    End With
        L = L + 1
    End If
Next i

Err:
Select Case Err.Number
Case -2147220973                                    'Could be because of Internet Connection
    MsgBox "Check your internet connection." & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
Case -2147220975                                     'Incorrect credentials User ID or password
    MsgBox "Check your login credentials and try again." & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
Case 0                              'Case 0 means code run smoothly and you need to exit this sub.
    GoTo Exit_Err:
Case Else                                                   'Report other errors
    MsgBox "Error encountered while sending email." & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End Select
Resume Exit_Err
Exit_Err:

'Release object memory
Set NewMail = Nothing
Set mailConfiguration = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

MsgBox "Email sent : " & L & " Nos."
t2 = Timer()
MsgBox "Time taken to run this code: " & t2 - t1

End Sub
```

Comment: As you say your code is working, then post on the Code Review stack - they may help improve it.

Comment: Outlook may faster than `CDO`.

Comment: How much faster? @Harun24HR